# FontLab: change (scale) font size for browser

Tags: fontlab-studio

I have an OTF font. Currently, in a browser my preferred `font-size` for it is `16`, what should I edit in this font, using **FontLab Studio 5**, to make this font appear **the same size visually**, but if `font-size` is set to `14`.

Comment: Do you *want* to change a font, or do you only want to have a scaled font size in your browser? That can be far easier achieved with a local CSS. (Instructions on how to create and apply a local CSS for your OS and browser can be found with regular search engines.)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
File->Font Info -> Metrics and Dimensions
- Change UPM uncheck `Scale all glyphs...` to for example `ORIGINAL_UPM * 14 / 16`
- Apply
- Change UPM back to ORIGINAL_UP, check `Scale all glyphs...`
- Apply
```